# How do I automatically send data from google sheets to a wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets

I have a leaderboard in Google Sheets that I would like to automatically upload to a WordPress webpage. Are there any ways I can automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [publish to web](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308870) option on Google Sheets and then embed your Sheet file (with your leader-board data) to your WordPress web page by referring to the section **[Embed files](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/183965#embed_files)** on the steps for ***Embed a document, spreadsheet, or presentation***.

Similarly, you may also refer to WordPress' official steps for [Embedding sheets from Google Docs to WordPress](https://wordpress.com/support/google-docs/#sheets).

Lastly, to ensure that whenever you update the sheet file, the embedded sheet data also updates automatically on your WordPress site, you may want to double check the "***Automatically republish when changes are made***" checkbox before publishing, as seen here:

[image]